# Jquery Conflict How to handle the situation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, conflict

I have recently applied a new theme and it include 2 jquery files that are conflicting with the widget area. I figured out the 2 files but really don't know how I am going to use jquery noconlict on them? Any help will be great. I am newbie and don't really understand others are talking about jquery conflict I tried examples given here but didn't work. Here are the 2 files.

The first file
http://jsfiddle.net/7mdDs/

The second file
http://jsfiddle.net/KVPY3/

They are conflicting with the wordpress admin area.
The files are called in function.php by this parameter

```
function PricerrTheme_admin_stylesheet()
{
?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/tipTip.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/admin.css" type="text/css" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/layout.css" />
    <link type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.tipTip.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/idtabs.js"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php

            $tb = "tabs1";
            if(isset($_GET['active_tab'])) $tb = $_GET['active_tab']; 

        ?>  
            var $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function() {      
            $("#usual2 ul").idTabs("<?php echo $tb; ?>");
            $(".tltp_cls").tipTip({maxWidth: "330"}); 
        });



        </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/colorpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/eye.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>    

    <?php   

}
```

The console is giving the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined load-scripts.php:2
v.extend.each load-scripts.php:2
e.widget load-scripts.php:13
e.widget.version load-scripts.php:18
(anonymous function)
```

Please tell me How I can use jquery no-conflict to use these files.

Comment: any specific reason to use both library?

Comment: I really don't know if they are both liberaries -- The theme include them and without them the theme not functioning properly.. by the way they are not conflicting with each other but conflicting with the admin panel of wordpress I cant drag drop or open widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: Removes confliction with any other library
$.noConflict();

Comment: Can you please briefly demonstrate how to use this and where to use this ? I mean the js files are calling in function.php so ? where do I have to put $.noconflict(); and what's the perameter ? Sorry I am really newbie in js.

Comment: <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script> , otherwise put $.noConflict() in your js file

Answer (score 0):

```
$.noConflict();
```

here is complete [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

I hope it will help.

Comment: You have been so nice.. but Actually I can't understand the documentation that is why I asked here a breif question on how to exactly use it .. documentation states.. <script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here. ??? What is the code here ???
</script>

Comment: use $.noConflict(); between after first literary and before second.

Comment: Can you please define it as I defined in function.php in my question ?